# git - some general Thing regarding to git structure in our special circumstances and setting up git

Tags: git, gitlab

my name is Björn, I'm from Germany and I have some general Questions about git I hope you can help with.

We are programming a Web-Application in ColdFusion.
We usually have two Sites per Customer. One is for testing and one ist live. Both are working on our CF-WebServer and both are not identical. In fact, it is not possible to have both sites absolutely identical, because of some configuration lines.

Now we're trying to get all of our Projects into gitlab. Problem is, that we won't start from scratch.

I tried this:
I crated a new Repository in our Testsystem-Folder and pushed this to Master. Then I created a Live-Branch.
After that I copied the .git Folder from Test to Live and pushed the differences into Live Branch.
Now I have the Live-System at the Live Branch and the Test-System at the Master-Branch.

When I start workin, I create a local Branch from master (Test-System) and do my work in here. When I'm done, I merge this to the Test-System, so that our Consultants are able to test. After that I merge the same Branch to the Live-System. The Problem is, that at this point I merge the whole Master-Branch to Live and not just my last changes regarding to my Ticket which will be stored in one to x commits.

Now I'm not sure, if our way is the right one or not. I hope I explained it good enough and I hope, that someone is able to help me out of this misery.

Thanks and regards

Björn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [git-flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/), in some cases it is overreled. You can minified this workflow by using only two additional branches (`live` and `test`). If you are starting to fix a new issue:

1. Create a feature branch (named e.g., `feature/#1`) from `master`.
2. If you finished your work create a merge request from `feature/#1` into `test`, so the consultant can test. If the test will be rejected fix the issue on the feature branch and merge again.
3. If the test is passed, merge the `feature/#1` into `master` to make the changes ready for production and create a merge request from `master` into `live`.

Use webhooks or the GitLab pipeline to deploy your changes on push events in `test` or `live` to your different servers.

Note that you don't have a release management, all changes go into live when merging. Hotfixes need to be solved on the master branch and have to be merged into `live` and `test`. But in this solution you have control on the test and live system independent of the `master` branch. In case of rest a branch you need to do this on the specific branch or make a hard reset on master branch and merge into test and live.